# I want to Initialize a second form, both containing an input and retrieve both values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form with a single input that may need to be duplicated, how can I grab the two values when they exist on what I assume is a separate form because the component 1 has 1 input box and component 2(duplicated) has 1 input box

maybe this helps: user has one college class so the 1 component has an input box for the name but then the user needs to add a second input (copy of component 1) with an input box. How can I grab both values entered?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0QS.png)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I have a component with form that gets an additional input field (component 1: input 1, component 2: input 1 (copy)) they are in two different instances of the component and I need to retrieve both values, the only value im getting is the second value, so I assume its overwriting the first.

Comment: Please send me more details at my email id `grdtechlab@gmail.com` . It will be more easy to communicate over there. Thank You.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.